# Multinomial likelihood function with data for only 2 of 3 outcomes

Tags: binomial-distribution, missing-data, likelihood, multinomial-distribution, parameterization

Can/should I use a binomial likelihood function if the data were generated from a multinomial process (3 possible outcomes) but data were only collected for two of the possible outcomes?

In each trial of the experiment there are three possible outcomes (x,y,z). However, the experimenters only counted the number of x and y outcomes, and there are no data for outcome z. It's therefore impossible to calculate what proportion of the total was outcome x or y (e.g., z is unknown in x/(x+y+z)). Should I just use a binomial likelihood and ignore the possibility of z?

Comment: Write down both the binomial and trinomial likelihoods for the data: how do they differ?  Does that matter in your application?